# Iterating through dictionary values that are arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
{'Francisco Partners': [45000000],
 'Bpifrance': [45000000, 15000000,87000000,15000000,...],
...}
```

I wrote this code to take it, go through each key and taking the max, median and min of the corresponding values (that are arrays)

```
srs = [["name", "max", "med", "min"]]

for key, value in dct:
    srs_row = []
    srs_row.append(key)
    srs_row.append(max(value))
    srs_row.append(median(value))
    srs_row.append(min(value))
    srs.append(srs_row)
```

When I run the program, I get this error, pointing to the "for ..." line:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What does the machine tries to put in "value", if not an array ?
Hence, is there a way to unload the values as an array, to iterate through after ?

Best,

Comment: for key, value in dct.items():

Comment: Iterating over a dictionary will iterate over the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dictionary.items` to iterate through `dct`

```
for key, value in dct.items():
   #Code
```

Comment: thanks, indeed just forgot the .items().